# Delaying before reconnect with fauria/vsftpd

Tags: docker, ftp, vsftpd

I try to use `fauria/vsftpd` to get a local FTP server for testing purposes. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work.

For convenience, I put the configuration in a `docker-compose.yml`. The file is listed below.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  ftp:
    image: fauria/vsftpd:latest
    container_name: vsftpd-compose
    restart: always
    environment:
      - FTP_USER=admin
      - FTP_PASS=passwd
      - PASV_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
      - PASV_MIN_PORT=21100
      - PASV_MAX_PORT=21110
      - LOG_STDOUT=yes
    ports:
      - 20:20
      - 21:21
      - "21100-21110:21100-21110"
```

I try to connect to this via `lftp "localhost" -p 21100 -u admin,passwd`. Once I issue the first command, e.g. `ls` or `PUT file`, I get an error message: *Pausiere vor erneuter Verbindung* (translated: *Delaying before reconnect*).

How can I get this working?

Comment: From the closing message: >>This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers.<< I would consider Docker and a local FTP server to be >>software tools primarily used by programmers<<. If that does not convince you, I'd like to ask where else to put the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues above.

First, all port mappings must be quoted. I thought only the PASV range must be quoted, but one must use `"20:20"` and `"21:21"` too.

Second, the PASV range must not be used to connect to the FTP. One still must use port 21. Thus, the `lftp` command is: `lftp "localhost" -p 21 -u admin,passwd`.